# why CLONE_NEWNS can not make mount namespace isolated?

Tags: linux, linux-namespaces

[namespace link](https://gist.github.com/gdamjan/858453)

and do following test:

> 1. gcc -o mntns  mntns.c
> 2. the run with $ sudo ./mntns
> 3. secret_dir='mktemp -d --tmpdir=/tmp'
> 4. mount -n -o size=1m -t tmpfs tmpfs $secret_dir
> 5. df -h , show it includes the tmpdir created in step 3, /tmp/tmp.sFsCzTDhjE
> 6. open another shell console, run df -h, it also includes /tmp/tmp.sFsCzTDhjE

So it seems the CLONE_NEWNS can not make mounts isolated, still can be seen in other mount namespace.
Could someone helped this question ? Searched a lots of examples, they just tried this, but not talked about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. you can check this comment #2
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194388

it helped this issue, and solved the visible namespace question asked before.